# ¿como cambiar la forma de una ventana en winapi?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Estoy intentando crear un botón personalizado con WinAPI en c++. para eso he creado una clase de ventana y la he introduzco como ventana hija dentro de la princiapal de momento funciona pero es un cuadrado feo. Se que puedo hacerlo un poco más bonito con WM_PAINT y si le pongo de color de fondo el color de la ventana principal y pinto el botón encima parecerá que tiene una forma diferente pero aun así si clico en el fondo "invisible" seguirá considerando que se ha clicado el botón.

La pregunta es como puedo hacer para que ese fondo no sea considerado como parte de la ventana.

Esto es la parte de mi código que se ocupa del botón:

```
    //Aquí creo la clase para la ventana.

    WNDCLASSEX perso; 

    perso.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    perso.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    perso.lpszClassName = L"personalizada";
    perso.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure2;
    perso.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS;

    perso.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    perso.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    perso.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    perso.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    perso.cbClsExtra = 0;                   
    perso.cbWndExtra = 0;

    perso.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,255));

    RegisterClassEx(&perso);

    //Esta es la función CALLBAK de la ventana principal (He quitado todo lo que no tiene que ver)

    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
     case WM_CREATE:

        CreateWindowEx(0, L"personalizada", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE ,0 , 0 ,100,100,hwnd (HMENU)INTEGRADO, GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);

        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0); 
        break;

    default:            
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

//Esta es la función CALLBACK de la ventana hija que he creado.

    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure2(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
                //aqui iría lo que quiero hacer cuando pulso el botón
        }
    
        break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Agradecería mucho si alguien pudiese ayudarme .

Espero haber explicado bien mi problema XD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final depues de hacer unas pruebas la manera de hacerlo es usando la funcion `SetWindowRect()` hay obviamente que crear un `RECT` antes. Las coordenadas de ese `RECT` se colocan respecto al area de cliente de la ventana que hay que cambiar.

Yo el código con el que he hecho las pruebas es con el siguiente:

```
    //TV es una variable que contiene el alto y el ancho de la ventana

    HRGN general;
    HRGN region1;
    HRGN region2;
    HRGN region3;

    general = CreateRectRgn(0,0,0,0); //Esto sirve solo para inicilizar general que sino el compilador da un aviso
    region1 = CreateRectRgn(TV.alto / 2, 0, TV.ancho - TV.alto/2, TV.alto);
    region2 = CreateEllipticRgn(0, 0, TV.alto, TV.alto);
    region3 = CreateEllipticRgn(TV.ancho - TV.alto, 0, TV.ancho, TV.alto);

    CombineRgn(general, region3, region2, RGN_OR);
    CombineRgn(general, region1, general, RGN_OR);

    SetWindowRgn(identificador, general, TRUE);
    DeleteObject(region1);
    DeleteObject(region2);
    DeleteObject(region3);
```